# Android disable screen dimming in NativeActivity

Tags: android, native-activity

I need to disable/enable screen dimming from NativeActivity (when rendering is performed by OpenGL). I have inherited MyNativeActivity:

```
public class MyNativeActivity extends NativeActivity {
    public final void disableAutoSleep()
    {
        Log.d("TWP", "disableAutoSleep()...");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {          
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then I call this method from my native code using JNI. What I see in LogCat is:

```
06-03 16:51:26.964: D/TWP(2531): disableAutoSleep()...
06-03 16:51:27.034: E/BufferQueue(125): [com.example.MyNativeActivity]
    dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
06-03 16:51:27.034: W/nvwsi(2531): dequeueBuffer failed, error -19
```

and then `glGetError()` (in my rendering routine) returns `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION` and screen becomes black.

It seems that Android terminates or recreates my drawing window in response to `getWindow().addFlags(...)`. But I do not get any notifications in `engine_handle_cmd` (that is main C++ message callback in native activity). How do I handle it or what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I tried

```
ANativeActivity_setWindowFlags(state->activity, AWINDOW_FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, 0);
```

but also resulted in

```
06-03 18:34:47.054: E/BufferQueue(125): [com.example.MyNativeActivity] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
```

Comment: `this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);` What about this?

Comment: @Gunaseelan I talk about disabling auto-sleep feature.

Comment: `setKeepScreenOn(true)`?

Comment: @Gunaseelan `setKeepScreenOn` is applied to a View, not to Activity.

Comment: @Nick Did you manage to figure out a solution? we're just running into the same issue.

Comment: I'm currently facing this same issue. My workaround is to use `PowerManager.WakeLock`. It's deprecated but at least it seems to work.